# How to get console view of parameterised BigQuery query?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm running parameterised BigQuery queries inside a Flask app exactly as described in [Google's docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries).

I'm seeing some unexpected results, so simply want to print the query to my terminal/console for debug purposes. When I do this on only see the query with the parameterised placeholders, not the values.

Does anyone know how to get a view of the query with the values being run?

For example:

```
query = "select * from dogs where breed = @dog_breed"

query_params = [
    bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("dog_breed", "STRING", "kokoni")
]

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()

job_config.query_parameters = query_params

print(query) # This will only print query as above, not with value 'kokoni'

query_job = client.query(
    query,
    job_config=job_config,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [list_jobs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage/jobs.html) method to retrieve the information from the [Job class](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/reference.html#job), like in the example below:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

# List the 3 most recent jobs in reverse chronological order.
# Omit the max_results parameter to list jobs from the past 6 months.
print("Last 3 jobs:")
for job in client.list_jobs(max_results=3):  # API request(s)
    print(job.query)
    print(job.query_parameters)
```